# Basic setup for React with react-router and requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, reactjs

I'm trying to get the [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) up and running, but somehow React is not defined within react-router and because of that fails with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined
```

I'm also getting this error later:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: jsx!testapp_unnormalized2,jsx!testapp
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here? I simply want to get the router working without concatenating all the files.

This is how the app looks:

**index.html**

```
<!-- ... -->

    <script data-main="../resources/js/init" src="../resources/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

</body>

<!-- ... -->
```

**init.js**

```
require.config({

  paths: {
    react: "/resources/bower_components/react/react-with-addons",
    JSXTransformer: "/resources/bower_components/jsx-requirejs-plugin/js/JSXTransformer",
    jsx: "/resources/bower_components/jsx-requirejs-plugin/js/jsx",
    jquery : "/resources/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery",
    'react-router' : "/resources/bower_components/react-router/dist/react-router",
    'react-router-shim': 'react-router-shim'
  },

  shim : {

    'react-router': {
      deps:    ['react'],
      exports: 'Router'
    }
  },
});

require(['jsx!testapp'], function(App){
  var app = new App();
  app.init();
});
```

**react-router-shim.js**

```
define(['react'], function(React) {
  "use strict";

  window.React = React;
});
```

**testapp.js**

```
define(function(require){
  var React = require('react');
  var Router = require('react-router');

  var Route = Router.Route;
  var NotFoundRoute = Router.NotFoundRoute;
  var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
  var Link = Router.Link;
  var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

  var routes = (
    <Route handler={Home} path="/">
      <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
    </Route>
  );

  var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return(
        <p>This is the mathias page</p>
      );
    }
  });

  var App;

  App.init = function () {
    Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
      React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('content'));
    });
  };

  return App;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-router doesn't support AMD and thus won't load the React dependency by default. Instead, you should load React first and set it as a global (`window.React = React`), or use the RequireJS [shim configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to load React as a global.

See [react-router#171](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/171) for more discussion around react-router and AMD.